# setState a props from Parent component

Tags: reactjs

I'm having a lot of trouble to close my Modal component once my request is done.

My method togglePop works fine with the handleClick method i have in my modal component(I did not included here).

What i m trying to do is to reverse the "Togglepop" method into the state of Modal.js. Then, setState in my axios sbmit.

Avaibaliities.js

```
    this.state = {
      showModal: false
    };
  }
  validation = () => {
    if (this.state.showDate) {
      this.setState({
        showModal: true
      });
    } 

  togglePop = () => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      showModal: !prevState.showModal
    }));
  };

  render() {
{this.state.showModal && <Modal dateModal={this.state.date} toggle={this.togglePop} />} }
```

Modal.js

```
 state = {
    mailFilled: '',
    sent: false,
    showPopup: false,
    closeModal: !this.props.toggle
  };

  handleSubmit = (event) => {
    let data = {
      mailFilled: this.state.mailFilled,
      dateIn: dateFirst,
      dateOut: dateSecond
    };
    axios
      {
          this.setState(
            {
              sent: true,
              showPopup: true
            }
          )
          setTimeout(() => {
            this.setState({
              showPopup: false
            })
          }, 3000);
          this.setState({
             showPopup: false,
          closeModal: this.props.toggle
          })
```

This is kinda new for me. I really want to understand what im a doing wrong.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm just reading over the code without trying it myself. Should closeModal be false to close it? If so, I think you need to do `closeModal: this.props.toggle()` since it's a function, it needs to be invoked and not just referenced.

Comment: It works!! Thanks a lot. I didnt pay attention  to this.

Comment: Sweet! I just put it in a solution, if you're happy, you may accept it. Best wishes!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it's a function, I think it needs to be invoked and not just referenced

```js
this.setState({
  showPopup: false,
  closeModal: this.props.toggle()
});
```